# how to see what caused reputation increase / decrease

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-graph

I see a lot of questions about "what caused my reputation to drop?"

Is there a simple way to see what caused my reputation to go up / down within a time window?  I'd like to be able to go to my profile page and see a listing (much like the activity listing) which shows reputation activity, in timeline order, for some defined time window.

I realize I can highlight a range on the Reputation Graph and see what contributed to that range.  But it doesn't work well for discovering changes in the last hour or day, for example.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work well".  You can highlight a day and see everything for that day.  Are you trying to see what happened each hour?

Comment: I say it doesn't work well for two reasons.  1) cant zoom in on the graph for finer resolution.  2) it's hard to select just the last day - if you click too far to the right (last couple pixels) it wont let you.  Yes, I'd like to see what happened in the last hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click envelope icon next to user name.  Click reputation tab.  Optionally, click Today button (or other time period) to reset to the full day in your time zone.  Note that you won't be able to see changes (decreases) caused by votes being taken away, including accepted answers.  Also, check out https://stackoverflow.com/reputation for a complete audit, though again, you won't see reputation lost as a result of votes or acceptances being taken away.

Comment: That's it, thank you.  I never knew what that envelope did, and I guess I was never bothered to click it.  Why isn't that info presented alongside the profile stats/activity/reputation tab group?